# Minimum values for a list box VB 2015

Tags: vb.net

i need help calculating the lowest grade in a list box i had it working but i forgot what i did and also forgot to save now its not doing anything and just outputting 0

```
Private Sub btncalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalc.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To lstgrade.Items.Count - 1
        sum = sum + CInt(lstgrade.Items(i))

        If lstgrade.Items(i) < 100 Then
            min = lstgrade.Items(i)
        Else


        End If
    Next

    avg = sum / lstgrade.Items.Count
    txtlow.Text = min
    txtavg.Text = CStr(avg)
```

Comment: Is this a VBA question or a VB.NET question? Either the tag or the title should change to reflect which.

Comment: Please read again what you wrote as your requirement. Then compare each line of code to your requirement. You'll see where there's a mismatch. This is not a programming problem; it is about translating requirements into code which is a habit that needs to be learnt very early in programming education. If you learn that yourself it'll stay with you forever. To repeat, this what you need to do: **Please read again what you wrote as your requirement. Then compare each line of code to your requirement.** You'll find the problem.

Comment: In addition to MikeC's answer, remember to initialize variables, so you start from a known state (but that is not the only little change you have to make. there is one more).

Comment: You first need to have a look at this site to learn basic debugging. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html Aside from the comment from @Jens about initializing your variables, you are going to have to look through your code as it runs. Somewhere there is a runtime problem